# BS2 inconsistant pin state when connected to wire?

Tags: microcontroller

I have a BS2 mounted on a Parallax Board of Education Rev D.
I was trying to use a wire to determine whether a control was pressed. 
however, whenever there's a wire connected the state seems to fluctuate between 1 and 0 instead of staying one or the other. when connected to the desired button it still exhibits this behavior but has the added quality of switching to zero when the button is pressed. ideally it will stay zero while the buttons pressed and 1 when it's not, but instead it flickers between 1 and 0 when unpressed. 
what causes this behavior and why does it occur even when the wire is not connected to anything except the bus?
the code used to get the state is

```
DO
DEBUG CRSRXY,0,3,
"P5:", BIN1 IN5,
LOOP
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're in need of a [pull-up resistor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull-up_resistor).  This will help keep the input fixed at one value when disconnected.